# What VIF value limit (like 4,5,6,7,....) should I select for Linear Regression model which has 30 discrete variables and 4 continuous variables?

Tags: linear-regression

What should be the VIF value limit (like 4,5,6,7,....) for Linear Regression model which has 30 discrete, 4 continuous input variables and 1 continuous variable?

It's confusing to see that different researcher recommend different VIF values to use.

I have tried it in SPSS and by creating dummy variables for discrete variables. Here is the result

Coefficients
Model       Unstandardized Coefficients     Standardized Coefficients   t   Sig.    Collinearity Statistics 
        B   Std. Error  Beta            Tolerance   VIF
    (Constant)  .076    1.262       .060    .952
    absences    .014    .012    .020    1.170   .243    .776    1.289
    G1  .129    .039    .109    3.326   .001    .214    4.665
    G2  .857    .036    .773    23.541  .000    .215    4.645
    age .027    .050    .010    .548    .584    .649    1.540
    school_new  -.170   .135    -.025   -1.265  .206    .588    1.702
    sex_new .150    .121    .023    1.239   .216    .680    1.471
    address_new -.119   .127    -.017   -.937   .349    .712    1.405
    famsize_new .038    .118    .005    .320    .749    .830    1.205
    pstatus_new .004    .169    .000    .025    .980    .786    1.272
    
schoolsup_new  .197    .178    .019    1.105   .269    .811    1.234
    
famsup_new -.070   .110    -.011   -.632   .528    .836    1.197
    
paid_new   .147    .222    .011    .659    .510    .865    1.156
    
activities_new -.009   .108    -.001   -.087   .931    .830    1.204
    
nursery_new    .070    .132    .009    .531    .596    .879    1.137
    
higher_new -.124   .189    -.012   -.655   .513    .712    1.404
    
internet_new   -.115   .134    -.015   -.858   .391    .755    1.324
    
romantic_new   .022    .112    .003    .200    .842    .832    1.202
    
M_prim_edu -.046   .556    -.006   -.083   .934    .046    21.942
    
M_5th_TO_9th   -.114   .560    -.016   -.203   .839    .038    26.474
    
M_secon_edu    -.143   .566    -.018   -.253   .801    .045    22.328
    
M_higher_edu   -.309   .583    -.042   -.529   .597    .036    27.719
    
F_prim_edu -.454   .518    -.062   -.875   .382    .046    21.795
    
F_5th_TO_9th   -.318   .522    -.046   -.608   .543    .041    24.624
    
F_secon_edu    -.300   .532    -.037   -.563   .574    .053    18.873
    
F_higher_edu   -.269   .547    -.033   -.492   .623    .051    19.613
    
M_health_job   -.195   .253    -.025   -.770   .441    .229    4.373
    
M_other_job    .050    .256    .004    .197    .844    .541    1.849
    
M_services_job -.273   .225    -.041   -1.211  .226    .199    5.016
    
M_teacher_job  -.013   .226    -.002   -.055   .956    .286    3.496
    
F_health_job   .470    .335    .036    1.400   .162    .355    2.814
    
F_other_job    .003    .362    .000    .008    .993    .539    1.854
    
F_services_job .151    .269    .023    .563    .574    .136    7.336
    
F_teacher_job  .015    .275    .002    .054    .957    .159    6.293
    
reason_school_repu .239    .194    .031    1.235   .217    .364    2.746
    
reason_course_pref .176    .202    .023    .873    .383    .347    2.886
    
reason_other   .364    .175    .056    2.074   .039    .320    3.129
    
guard_mother   -.030   .129    -.004   -.234   .815    .699    1.431
    
guard_other    .311    .259    .023    1.204   .229    .612    1.635
    
tra_time_15_TO_30min   .043    .120    .006    .356    .722    .764    1.309
    
tra_time_30_TO_60min   .274    .206    .023    1.327   .185    .745    1.342
    
tra_time_GT_60min  .791    .351    .038    2.254   .025    .816    1.225
    
study_2_TO_5hrs_time   .171    .129    .026    1.325   .186    .584    1.713
    
study_5_TO_10hrs_time  .151    .177    .017    .853    .394    .605    1.654
    
study_GT_10hrs_time    .073    .253    .005    .290    .772    .743    1.347
    
failure_1_time -.532   .189    -.051   -2.814  .005    .704    1.421
    
failure_2_time -.691   .362    -.033   -1.906  .057    .766    1.305
    
failure_3_time -.428   .375    -.019   -1.140  .255    .813    1.230
    
family_rela_bad    -.002   .381    .000    -.004   .997    .391    2.558
    
family_rela_avg    .012    .322    .001    .038    .970    .177    5.642
    
family_rela_good   .011    .303    .002    .037    .971    .106    9.470
    
family_rela_excel  -.101   .308    -.014   -.329   .743    .127    7.885
    
freetime_low   .105    .236    .012    .447    .655    .315    3.172
    
freetime_avg   -.038   .217    -.006   -.174   .862    .217    4.600
    
freetime_high  -.026   .231    -.004   -.111   .911    .228    4.384
    
freetime_very_high -.153   .266    -.014   -.572   .567    .363    2.753
    
go_out_low .095    .223    .012    .424    .672    .280    3.576
    
go_out_avg .135    .218    .019    .619    .536    .236    4.244
    
go_out_high    .186    .232    .024    .801    .423    .264    3.781
    
go_out_very_high   -.132   .246    -.015   -.537   .591    .284    3.521
    
Dalc_low   -.157   .156    -.019   -1.006  .315    .655    1.527
    
Dalc_avg   .274    .250    .021    1.097   .273    .628    1.592
    
Dalc_high  -.877   .352    -.043   -2.488  .013    .763    1.310
    
Dalc_very_high .102    .407    .005    .250    .802    .571    1.751
    
Walc_low   .031    .144    .004    .213    .831    .656    1.526
    
Walc_avg   -.148   .164    -.018   -.901   .368    .594    1.683
    
Walc_high  .000    .205    .000    .002    .998    .495    2.020
    
Walc_very_high -.059   .309    -.005   -.190   .849    .393    2.542
    
health_low -.065   .205    -.006   -.314   .754    .542    1.845
    
health_avg -.125   .185    -.015   -.677   .499    .459    2.179
    
health_high    -.088   .190    -.010   -.465   .642    .482    2.075
    
health_very_high   -.234   .169    -.035   -1.381  .168    .357    2.801
a. Dependent Variable: G3

Comment: Welcome! Your Question is too vague. Please mention what you have tried to solve the problem: Show and summarize the sources of the recommendations  you mention such that people do not need to repeat your research. Also you might be off topic here, as your question seems to be about statistics. Maybe you're better of at [Cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), but be sure to read their [best practices](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking.

Comment: In case your question is moved to Cross Validated by a moderator, you might consider to [edit] your question to provide more detail...

Comment: Hii akraf, I have edited it including SPSS results. Here many of the variables are dummy.